# Spinner with arrow in left

Tags: android, android-spinner, right-to-left

I'm developing an app for RTL language and want to change the position of arrow to the left of Spinner ! 
Is there anyway to do this without creating a custom spinner ?

Comment: Add a coment and explain why downVote ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must write a custom spinner.
Sample code is below. You can edit as you wish.

```
<Spinner
            style="@style/spinner_style"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap content"
             />
```

@style/spinner_style:

```
 <style name="spinner_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/background_spinner</item>
</style>
```

@drawable/background_spinner

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item><layer-list>
        <item><shape>
               <solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
                <corners android:radius="4dp" />
                <padding android:left="8dp"/>
            </shape></item>
        <item><bitmap android:gravity="left"
              android:src="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_grey600_36dp"/>                
        </item>
    </layer-list></item>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

An easy and simple way to set arrow in left side is,You must create .xml file in drawable folder for that as written below:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

   <item>
        <shape android:shape="rectangle">
            <solid android:color="@color/colorWhite" />
        </shape>
   </item>
   <item
        android:drawable="@drawable/ic_arrow_drop_down_black_24dp"
        android:right="320dp"/>
</layer-list>
```

You can adjust above code as your need.
And set this file as background of a spinner widget as below:

```
<Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/layout_spinner"
        android:background="@drawable/arrow_left"
        android:elevation="5dp"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

This worked in my case. I have English and Arabic languages in my app

```
<Spinner
    android:textDirection="locale"
    android:id="@+id/spnGender"
    style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Spinner.Underlined"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:entries="@array/array_gender"/>
```

This attribute is important.

**`android:textDirection="locale"`**

NOTE : I have used the default spinner without any customizations.

Comment: This is the most correct solution. This one should be the accepted answer here.

Answer (score 3):

- Create a .xml in drawable folder : **@drawable/spinner_arrow.xml**

```
<item>

    <layer-list>

        <item>
            <shape>
                <gradient android:angle="90" android:endColor="#ffffff" android:startColor="#ffffff" android:type="linear" />

                <stroke android:width="1dp" android:color="#ECF0F1" />

                <corners android:radius="5dp" />

                <padding android:bottom="3dp" android:left="3dp" android:right="3dp" android:top="3dp" />
            </shape>
        </item>

        <item         android:width="24dp"         android:height="24dp"         android:gravity="end|center_vertical"         android:drawable="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_down_black_24dp"         />

    </layer-list>

</item>
```

- Then add it to the styles.xml

```
<style name="spinner_style">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_arrow</item>
</style>
```

- then add it to the **spinner**

  style="@style/spinner_style"

Answer (score 2):

dummy.xml (drawable should be of very low size-24dp)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item>
        <layer-list android:opacity="transparent">
            <item android:width="100dp" android:end="300dp">
                <bitmap android:src="@drawable/down_button_dummy_dummy" android:gravity="center"/>
            </item>
        </layer-list>
    </item>
</selector>
```

layout file snippet

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardUseCompatPadding="true"
        app:cardElevation="5dp"
        >
     <Spinner
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:background="@drawable/dummy">

     </Spinner>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

[Click here for rendered layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aDmka.png)

Answer (score 0):

What about this ? 
First of all make sure that you enabled rtl support in AndroidManifest.xml

```
<application
...
android:supportsRtl="true"
...>
```

after that use this in your Spinner definition :

```
android:layoutDirection="rtl"
android:textDirection="rtl"
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way:  set in Spinner 'layoutDirection'= 'rtl'
[image]