# Left arrow in spinner

Tags: android, android-layout, spinner

Im useing this tutorial for make custom spinner
http://androidopentutorials.com/android-how-to-get-holo-spinner-theme-in-android-2-x/
But it has two issue for me
First , The arrow(triangle) is at right , but i want bring it left
Second , The dropdown list is aligned to left of spinner , but i want aligend to right of spinner
I have already tryed edit the Drawable folder for bring the arrow to left , but i cant
Tnx every body

Comment: Is here any body to help me?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Spinner with arrow in left](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28715036/spinner-with-arrow-in-left)